# Why is Word successively indenting paragraphs?

Tags: microsoft-word, email, microsoft-outlook, indent

I have a long, forwarded email chain that I would like to separate - each email starts on a new page. To do so, in Outlook 365 I saved the email as an "MHT file," then opened the file in Word 365. At the beginning of each email I added a page break. However, I noticed that each email is more and more left-indented (like they are when viewing a chain in Outlook) and I cannot get the indentations to go away. I highlighted all and set bullets, numbering, list to none; set the page margins to 1" above/below and 0.5" sides; and highlighted all and set paragraph > indent left to 0". It's still there.

What am I missing?

Comment: Posting an example document will be useful.

Comment: I can't get mine to indent to replicate the issue but an MHT file is an HTML(?) or XML(?) file so you can rename it's extension to ",txt" and open it with a text editor to see what formatting is causing the indentation.

Comment: What happens if you insert a section break instead of a page break?